# Regex: How can I get the parameter from function?

Tags: regex

I am working on getting parameter from a function string. For example, my function is named "translate". So all I need to do is to get everything inbetween "translate(" and ")".
Is there a way that i can use regex to do that? So far I have something like:

```
"/translate\((?<keyName>*)\)/i"
```

Unfortunately it's not working. Can anybody help me with this one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what's the overall goal? What do you intend to accomplish with the parameter name?

Comment: What about function names in side comments: `/* comment translate() */`? And in string literals: `str = " string translate() "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`translate\((.*?)\)` will match the whole function call and capture the parameter into backreference 1. So you can replace it with `\1` if you want to extract the parameter.

If you want to match only the parameter and the regex engine you're using supports look-behinds/look-aheads, you can use this one: `(?<=translate\().*?(?=\))`

Comment: Note that these solutions obviously don't support escaping ). So they won't match or capture translate("<*)))><") as intended.